# Execlp in child and send to pipe, result cause infinite loop

Tags: c, linux

I am doing this in a child process: `execlp ("wc", "wc" ,filename,"-l", NULL)` and redirecting the output in a pipe to read from father process.

All working good but when `wc` option doesn't find the specified file name it cause an infinite loop. Same thing with find option.

How can i check the output of `execlp` or what should i do to not get into this infinite loop?

this is the code from child created with fork:

```
close(1); 
if (dup (pipeCom[1]) != 1) 
{
 fprintf (stderr, "dup - 1\n");
 exit (1);  
}
execlp ("wc", "wc" ,filename,"-l", NULL);`
```

this is the code from parent process:

```
wait();
if ((num = read(pipeCom[0],&out,200))==0)   
perror("pipe error");   
else {
     out[num] = '\0';
     }
printf("%s",out);
```

Comment: The **output** is meant for **reading**, and based on your description I didn't even know there was any loop... how about you post a sscce showing the problem?

Comment: @loreb I edited the post and paste some code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Traditionally, control arguments like `-l` precede the file name arguments to commands.  Linux muddies the waters and allows it to work, but you're in for a shock if you move to other systems.  You should ensure you exit if `execlp()` ever returns; I think you should print an error message too. You also should consider using `dup2()` instead of `close()` and `dup()` — both work, but `dup2()` is shorter and more reliable. When you `dup()` a pipe descriptor to standard input or standard output, you should almost always immediately close the undupped descriptor (`close(pipeCom[1])` in your code).

Comment: Do you know if it is an infinite loop (with the CPU spinning), or is the problem that `wc` is waiting for input (not doing anything with the CPU)?

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan is absolutely right about dup2() and the position of the "-l" option.
That being said, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const char *filename = "/etc/passwd"; /* whatever */
        int pipeCom[2];
        char out[200];
        int num, status;
        if(pipe(pipeCom)) {
                perror("pipe");
                return 111;
        }
        if(argv[1])
                filename = argv[1];
        switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
                perror("fork");
                return 111;
        case 0:
                /* child */
                close(1);
                if (dup (pipeCom[1]) != 1)
                {
                        fprintf (stderr, "dup - 1\n");
                        exit (1);
                }
                execlp ("wc", "wc" ,filename,"-l", NULL); /* Jonathan! */
                perror("wc");
                return 111;

        default:
                /* parent */
                wait(&status);
                if ((num = read(pipeCom[0],&out,200))==0)
                        perror("pipe error");
                else {
                        out[num] = '\0';
                }
                printf("%s",out);
                break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Your original code wouldn't even compile because of wait() without parameters; simply fixing that led to a program that compiles and works on my system, so...
Can you post **exactly** the piece of code that is giving you trouble, explaining **exactly** how you compile/run it and **exactly** what is failing? My guts tell me that filename==NULL in your case, but if that is the case, it would have been a **lot** better to read it in your program than to imagine it ;p